# Flutter Could not find a command named "-" and Exception: Gradle task assemble Debug failed with exit code 64

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, mobile

> Could not find a command named "-".

> Usage: dart [] <command|dart-file> []

Global options:

```
-h, --help                 Print this usage information.
-v, --verbose              Show additional command output.
    --version              Print the Dart SDK version.
    --enable-analytics     Enable anonymous analytics.
    --disable-analytics    Disable anonymous analytics.
```

Available commands:

```
  analyze   Analyze the project's Dart code.
  compile   Compile Dart to various formats.
  create    Create a new project.
  format    Idiomatically format Dart source code.
  pub       Work with packages.
  run       Run a Dart program.
  test      Run tests in this package.
```

Run "dart help " for more information about a command.
See https://dart.dev/tools/dart-tool for detailed documentation.
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 64
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Which flutter command did you run in command terminal ?

Comment: I didn't use any command I started debugging from vscode and got this error.

Comment: please run -->  flutter doctor -v in your terminal  and share the details

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I had a similar issue to this, and here is what I found out.

So first things first, running "flutter doctor" gave me green lights across the board so I know that's not an issue.

I have my flutter SDK installed under my D drive (D:/flutter/bin)

Originally I tried to create a basic hello world project with this file structure: D:\Development\Flutter\Flutter & Dart - The Complete Guide\hello_world

So then when I ran the "flutter run" command I would be greeted with an error like this:

> Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you notice
> graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
> "--enable-software-rendering". Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone
> x86 in debug mode... Could not find a command named "-".
>
> Usage: dart <command|dart-file> [arguments]
>
> Global options:
> -h, --help                 Print this usage information.
> -v, --verbose              Show additional command output.
> --version              Print the Dart SDK version.
> --enable-analytics     Enable analytics.
> --disable-analytics    Disable analytics.
>
> Available commands:   analyze    Analyze Dart code in a directory.
> compile    Compile Dart to various formats.   create     Create a new
> Dart project.   devtools   Open DevTools (optionally connecting to an
> existing application).   doc        Generate HTML API documentation
> from Dart documentation comments.   fix        Apply automated fixes
> to Dart source code.   format     Idiomatically format Dart source
> code.   migrate    Perform null safety migration on a project.   pub
> Work with packages.   run        Run a Dart program.   test       Run
> tests for a project.
>
> Run "dart help " for more information about a command. See
> https://dart.dev/tools/dart-tool for detailed documentation. Running
> Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             822ms
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 64

So then I went a few directories back and created another hello_world project with the file path of: D:\Development\Flutter\hello_world

But this time when I ran the same "flutter run" command it actually worked.

My guess would be that there is some kind of issue with either the name of the folder used or how deeply nested the folders were.